# Android switch button issue on Samsung Device?

Tags: android

Am using switch button in Fragment and setting custom style to switch button.But on Samsung devices it shows default System theme.Then i moved same Layout file to Activity.If i set same layout to Activity it is working fine.

```
                        <Switch
                            android:id="@+id/switch_dict_fade_out"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_below="@id/linLayDilogPar2"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linLayDilogPar2"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@id/linLayDilogPar2"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:paddingTop="20dp"
                            android:text="@string/dictionary_fadeout"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_bg"
                            android:track="@drawable/switch_track_bg" />
```

### drawable/switch_bg.xml

```
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/off_switch" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/on_switch" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/off_switch"/>
```

### drawable/switch_track_bg.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/track_switch" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/track_switch"/>
```

Comment: can you post your code..

Comment: Only am facing problem on Samsung devices. Inside Activity it is fine but inside  Fragment it is showing default theme.

Comment: @lokesh, you about that Samsung's devices not apply a custom switch layout? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the attributes:

```
android:textOff=""
android:textOn=""    
android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
```